# Ruby use guard to assign variable inside if clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to replace below if clause by guard?

```
  end_date = if transaction_end_date.nil?
               (starts_in_the_future ? start_date : today) + MIN_END_DATE
             else
               transaction_end_date
             end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this instead

```
end_date = transaction_end_date
end_date ||= (starts_in_the_future ? start_date : today) + MIN_END_DATE
```

or just

```
end_date = transaction_end_date || 
           (starts_in_the_future ? start_date : today) + MIN_END_DATE
```